# WinForms C# Перемещение проги в панель скрытых приложений

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток программисты :3 . Я написал небольшую утилиту, и мне надо сделать так, что при нажатии на "закрыть" прога не закрывалась, а сворачивалась и оставалась в панели скрытых приложений(фото приложил). А при нажатии на иконку в той панели, прога разворачивалась.

Как мне это реализовать?

[image: Панель скрытых приложений]

Comment: а какое у вас приложение? консольное? winforms? wpf?

Comment: Забыл уточнить, WinForm

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread106071.html ?

Comment: [NotifyIcon](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.18.php при этом, скрыта будет иконка под галочку или нет, решает система и пользователь (управляется в настройках панели задач), приложение только может либо скрыть иконку из трея, либо добавить ее туда.